# Use cases for mongodb elasticsearch and redis

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, redis

I'm currently learning about elasticsearch & redis and I have some missunderstanding regarding when to use each service while I have a MongoDB service as my datastorage

I would like to understand which kind of data is saved on each service (not looking for the actual code/commands)

I understand that elasticsearch is used for actual search on huge data (big data) and redis is a in memory database which can store data structures and the use for redis is not ment to store data that has low usage

I'll appreciate if someone can help me and clearify some details
Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Both MongoDB and ElasticSearch store (a form of) JSON documents. Redis stores everything in memory and periodically dump to the disk.

MongoDB is meant to be the source of truth, see it as a replacement of SQL databases.

ElasticSearch is not meant to be a source of truth, it's designed for searching. See it as a search cache/engine that you populate from your source of truth.

Redis is not meant to be a source of truth, it is a key/value object store which is often used for caching. See it as a better Memcached.

The following page should help you https://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

There are lots of tools to choose from nowadays, often they overlap in scope and features, familiarize yourself with each of them and see where and when they are used to get a better idea.

Comment: The site from the link is exactly helpful and make this answer flexible.